# How to create a slingshot menu entry for a terminal command in Elementary OS?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, slingshot

I would need to add a new entry in the applications menu related to a command to be executed in the terminal and I tried to use this expression in the .desktop file:

```
Exec=pantheon-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd /opt/FlexServer; sudo ./lmgrd -c /opt/FlexServer/safe.lic; $SHELL'"
```

but it does not work in Elementary while a similar expression using gnome-terminal works in Ubuntu 18.04.
I tried to use the AppEditor utility too but without success.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try with `io.elementary.terminal ` instead of `pantheon-terminal`?

Comment: Thanks, io.elementary.terminal seems to be the right name for terminal. Following Your hint I have tried with -e or --execute= (i.e. io.elementary.terminal --execute="bash -c 'cd /opt/FlexServer; sudo ./lmgrd -c /opt/FlexServer/safe.lic; $SHELL'"), only the terminal opens but the commands doesn't work. Could it be a syntax error?